# Self patch cordova application

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova application for android written in html/js/css. I install a generated apk on a customer tablet, assuming i allow installing apk without store.

I would like to deploy my application versions repo on the file system of my tomcat server.

Is it possible that when my android app starts, i check with a rest api if my app is up to date. If not, i download new apk from my tomcat server to the tablet, i launch apk installation, restart the app, delete download apk file,  all that using cordova and plugins ...

Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileTransfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) plugin to download the new apk and the [FileOpener](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) plugin to open and begin installing the update. The examples in those docs should give you what you need.